# Unity3D v5.0 Pong/Breakout: Track balls on transparent "front" wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow, light

I'm working on a kind of break-out clone 3d thingy type game. This is what I have for my Arena so far:

[image]

The Arena is:

- Arena

  - Walls: 6 Cubes. Mesh Colliders. Front wall is "transparent".
  - Balls: n Balls. Rigidbodies. Bounce around, breaking out of stuff
  - Paddle: A cube or a circular shaped item that deflects based on where it's hit (To be fleshed out)
  - Bricks: Square thingies that disappear when hit (To be fleshed out)

What I've found is that it's hard'ish to track the balls in 3d... vs a "simple" 2d version.

As the balls bounce around, I want them to create "shadows" on the "transparent" "Front" wall. I think that'll make it easier to match paddle to ball during a "real" game.

How would you attach a "shadow" (Grows bigger/darker as ball gets closer to "front") to a transparent wall? On either side?

[Full Code](https://bitbucket.org/wernercd/unity.breakout/) at BitBucket, and the [BallScript](https://bitbucket.org/wernercd/unity.breakout/src/master/Assets/Prefabs/Balls/BallScript.cs) hidden therein.

Answer (score 0):

assuming x is left/right and y is up/down and z is close/far:

add an object (your shadow) for each ball on your front transparent wall and update its transform.position x and y with the x and y of the ball (keep z as it is)

to make it bigger / and or darker, use

Vector3.Distance( ball.transform.position, shadow.transform.position )

to calculate a factor. use this factor to set shadow.transform.scale and to change the color of the material of the shadow.

Comment: Added BitBucket repo link with current project code. I had originally tried doing a separate script to do this (Script attached to Wall that did something similar), but adding the "Shadow" to the individual Balls instead seems much more compact. I think most of my issues atm is moving stuff around from Parent to Grandparent and Position and LocalPosition - working in a 3d environment and all the relations -but occasionally I'll get it working fully with all the shadows following on the "Front" wall.